# How to detect death of parent in pre-fork server where all children block on accept()

Tags: sockets, unix, process, preforking

Suppose I have a pre-fork server. On start up, the server listens on a socket and forks multiple children. All children then block on their `accept()` system call until a client sends a request, upon which one of the children will handle the request. It is easy for the parent to detect the death of its children by using a SIGCHLD handler. But how can the children be informed about the death of their parent? All the children are blocking on their `accept()` call, so they would not be able to poll for the presence/absence of the parent.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Shawn The question is tagged "Unix". I am using Debian and FreeBSD.

Comment: Unix covers a lot of possibilities.

Comment: On Debian/Linux, there's `prctl(2)` which can be used to arrange to have a signal delivered to the process when its parent exits.

Comment: On FreeBSD, instead of blocking in `accept()`, you can use kqueue to wait for the socket to become readable or for a process to exit.

Comment: Or have each child start a thread that periodically checks to see if the parent pid has changed. That's probably the most portable approach.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you. I am primarily looking for a portable solution.